# Client-server. How to transfer to the client, a custom class?

Tags: java, object, io, client-server

I need reading data from database(MySQL) and transfer to client.

Can i somehow transfer the Object of type `TopickOfVote` to the client or only through String?
Writer and reader:

```
writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientAPP.getWriter()));
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientAPP.getReader()));
```

Server:

```
 private void LoadOfTopics() throws SQLException {
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM  kursach.TopicOfVote");
    StringBuffer id;
    StringBuffer topic;
    while(resultSet.next()){
        TopicOfVote topicOfVote = new TopicOfVote();
        topicOfVote.setId(Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("idVote")));
        topicOfVote.setTopic(resultSet.getString("topic"));
        ResultSet ans = statement.executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM kursach.Answers_vote WHERE idVote=" + topicOfVote.getId());
        ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (ans.next()){
            Answer answer = new Answer();
            answer.setId(Integer.parseInt(ans.getString("idAnswer")));
            answer.setAnswer(ans.getString("answer"));
            answer.setIdOfTopic(Integer.parseInt(ans.getString("idVote")));
            answers.add(answer);
        }
        topicOfVote.setAnswers(answers);
        writer.println(topicOfVote); // ???
        writer.flush(); 
        ans.close();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
    private void createPanelTopics(){
    try {
        writer.println(HandlerQueries.GET_VOTES + "?");
        writer.flush();
        reader.readLine();//?????
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: From were do you get `writer` and `reader`? if you must use them then you need to use text serialization (you can use JSON for example). If you have an `InputStream` and can make `TopicOfVote` `Serializable` then you can use `ObjectInputStream` and ``ObjectOutputStream``.

Comment: Thank you! Oddly. But,before, it not worked with `ObjectInputStream`  and `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: 'It not worked' is not a problem description. If that's what you want to ask about, ask it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i somehow transfer the Object of type TopickOfVote to the client

Yes, with Object Serialization, provided `TopickOfVote` implements `Serializable` and does all the other right things associated, such as defining a `private static final long serialVersionUID`, and doesn't evolve incompatibly.

> or only through String? Writer and reader:

Yes, with XML, JSON, ...